# MSSQL Group By Error in query

Tags: sql-server

I added Project_Contract.ContractorName but query got error.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

```
select top (100) percent dbo.Project_Profile.Project_ID
    ,dbo.Project_Contract.ContractorName
    ,dbo.Schemes.Scheme_Name as [Name of Project]
    ,dbo.Program_Ctrl.Program_Title as [Contract Status]
    ,dbo.District_Ctrl.District_Name as District
    ,M.Module_Title as Module
    ,(
        select MAX(Progress_Percentage) as Expr1
        from dbo.Progress_Reporting as PR
        where (M.ModuleID = Module_Id)
            and (dbo.Milestone_Ctrl.Milestone_ID = Project_Milestone_ID)
            and (Progress_Type = 'A')
        ) as Milestone_Percent_Share
    ,dbo.Milestone_Ctrl.Milestone_Title
from dbo.District_Ctrl
inner join dbo.Project_Profile
inner join dbo.Project_Profile
inner join dbo.Project_Contract
    on dbo.Project_Profile.Project_ID = dbo.Project_Contract.ProjectId
inner join dbo.Schemes
    on dbo.Project_Profile.Scheme_id = dbo.Schemes.Scheme_id
inner join dbo.Program_Ctrl
    on dbo.Project_Profile.Program_ID = dbo.Program_Ctrl.Program_ID
inner join dbo.Project_Modules
    on dbo.Project_Profile.Project_ID = dbo.Project_Modules.ProjectId
        on dbo.District_Ctrl.District_ID = dbo.Schemes.District_ID inner join dbo.Modules_Ctrl as M
        on M.ModuleID = dbo.Project_Modules.ModuleID 
inner join dbo.Milestone_Ctrl
inner join dbo.Project_Milestones
    on dbo.Milestone_Ctrl.Milestone_ID = dbo.Project_Milestones.Project_Milestone_ID
        on M.ModuleID = dbo.Project_Milestones.ModuleId 
group by dbo.Project_Profile.Project_ID
        ,dbo.Project_Contract.ContractorName
        ,dbo.Schemes.Scheme_Name
        ,dbo.Program_Ctrl.Program_Title
        ,M.Module_Title
        ,dbo.Project_Modules.ProjectModuleId
        ,dbo.Project_Milestones.Project_Milestone_ID
        ,dbo.District_Ctrl.District_Name
        ,dbo.Project_Milestones.Milestone_Percent_Share
        ,dbo.Project_Milestones.MileStoneId
        ,dbo.Milestone_Ctrl.Milestone_ID
        ,dbo.Milestone_Ctrl.Milestone_Title
        ,M.ModuleID
order by dbo.Project_Profile.Project_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two join with `Project_Profile` Table and have only one `ON` for this join you must add another ON for solve your problem or remove  `dbo.Project_Profile INNER JOIN` part command.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
                         dbo.Project_Profile INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Project_Profile INNER JOIN
```

Have duplicate Project_Profile without alias